# Hashmap converting to JSONObject every `/` in the hashmap item value is replacing with this `\/`

Tags: java, json, hashmap

When converting `HashMap` to `JSONObject`, every `/` in the string will replacing with this `\/`why is like this?? any solution for this?
my string is

```
 String sumValue= "mZftaLXj7UN19zxc/7n/UZdf....";
```

but i'm getting like this

```
D/b: getBody{"****":"*****","*****":"***",SUMHASH":"mZftaLXj7UN19zxc\/7n\/UZdf****"}
```

I'm tried like this

```
 public byte[] getBody() {

  String sumValue= "mZftaLXj7UN19zxc/7n/UZdf.....";

                    HashMap<String, String> params2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params2.put("***", "*****");
                    params2.put("***", "*****");
                    params2.put("SUMHASH", sumValue);

                    Log.d(TAG, "getBody" + new JSONObject(params2));

                    try {
                        return new JSONObject(params2).toString().getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }}
```

Given below is the output while doing

```
System.out.println("getBody" + new JSONObject(params2));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is just text representation of the result JSON. Really field *SUMHASH* contains no additional '\'.

Put object *new JSONObject(params2)* to new variable and try to get value of field *SUMHASH* from this object and you see original value of this field.

Comment: The problem is when I'm doing new JSONObject(params2).toString()
i'm getting the value with extra `\/`. what i want is, whatever i'm giving the same should be there.  while converting  toString

Comment: @Aabauser - It is NOT a problem.  The JSON spec says that `"\/"` is a correct way to represent a forward slash in a JSON string.  Look at the JSON syntax specs: http://json.org/

Comment: @Aabauser - this is correct textual representation of your JSON. Field value in JSON is correct and do not contains wrong symbols.

Comment: `return new JSONObject(params2).toString().getBytes("utf-8");`
this returing a wrong value why??

Answer (score 0):

Anton Tupy is right. There is no additional '\' in your output. You can test it by using System.out.println().

```
System.out.println("getBody" + new JSONObject(params2));
```

And here is the output

```
getBody{"SUMHASH":"mZftaLXj7UN19zxc/7n/UZdf.....","***":"*****"}
```

Comment: no its not, i'm still getting the same only :(
i'm updated the question with sreenshot